# Многопоточная запись в Clickhouse

Tags: java, mongodb, clickhouse

есть ли возможность многопоточной посредством JDBC записи в Clickhouse с MongoDB? Сталкивался ли кто с такими задачами?

Comment: у MongoDB есть поддержка реактивных драйверов, работает очень прилично (приходилось сталкиватсья). думаю, что копать имеет смысл в эту сторону. Clickhouse - очень специфическая штука, яндекс точил ее под аналитику. она работает круто только когда используется по назначению. прикручивать к ней реактивные драйвера не приходилось (даже не знаю, есть ли они в природе)

Comment: CH ожидает не поток коротких вставок, а одну большую - https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/introduction/performance/#performance-when-inserting-data